# How to disable syntactic indentation interactively in php-mode?

Tags: indentation, php-mode

I discovered that in php-mode, syntactic indentation makes rigid indentation very slow when the marked region is big. When I disable syntactic indentation, rigid indentation is not slow anymore.

So I made functions that disable syntactic indentation before indenting rigidly.

```
(defun my/indent-region-left-tab ()
  (interactive)
  (c-toggle-syntactic-indentation -1)
  (indent-rigidly (region-beginning) (region-end) -4)
  (c-toggle-syntactic-indentation 1)
  (setq deactivate-mark nil)
  )

(defun my/indent-region-right-tab ()
  (interactive)
  (c-toggle-syntactic-indentation -1)
  (indent-rigidly (region-beginning) (region-end) 4)
  (c-toggle-syntactic-indentation 1)
  (setq deactivate-mark nil)
  )
```

The problem is they don't seem to disable syntactic indentation, because they work just as slow. But if I use the next function before calling my/indent-region-left-tab or my/indent-region-right-tab, then the indentation is done fast:

```
(defun my/disable-syntactic-indentation ()
  (interactive)
  (c-toggle-syntactic-indentation -1)
  )
```

How to do it so it can be all put inside the functions so they are not slow anymore?

Comment: We need an example php-file (maybe html?) for reconstruction. Otherwise you will not get any valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing here because I can't replicate the issue, but do the following slightly different functions work?

```
(defun my/indent-region-left-tab ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((c-syntactic-indentation nil))
    (indent-rigidly (region-beginning) (region-end) -4))
  (setq deactivate-mark nil))

(defun my/indent-region-right-tab ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((c-syntactic-indentation nil))
    (indent-rigidly (region-beginning) (region-end) 4))
  (setq deactivate-mark nil))
```

Comment: They don't work, same issue.

Comment: That is a premature answer. Let @mikl give as much input as we need to reproduce the problem.